# Bar symbol over a matrix

Tags: matrices, notation

So I am reading a paper (not online) and I come across a definition:

$$\mathbb E=R\bar R$$

Where R is a complex matrix.  I am thinking that it means complex conjugate, but I honestly have never seen a bar used for that.  Can anyone provide examples of what the symbol is used for?

Comment: Your interpretation seems likely.

Comment: Complex conjugation is commonly denoted by $\overline{R}$, whether $R$ is a complex number, an $n$-tuple of complex numbers, a matrix with complex entries, a complex-valued function, ...

Answer (score 1):

The bar notation is often used in Lie Group theory.

For example, the $n \times n$ unitary matrices are defined as

$$U(n) := \{ X \in \mathrm{Mat}(n,\mathbb C): \overline{X}^{\top}\!X = E\}$$

where $\overline{X}^{\top}$ is the conjugate matrix of $X$ transposed, and $E$ is the identity matrix.

Just as the (real) orthogonal matrices $X^{\top}\!X=E$ preserve the (real) inner product
$$\langle u,v\rangle = u^{\top}v$$
the (complex) unitary matrices $\overline{X}^{\top}\!X = E$ preserve the (complex) Hermitian product
$$\langle u,v\rangle = \overline{u}^{\top}v$$

Could you tell us what $\mathbb{E}$ is, e.g. is it the identity matrix? If it is then I suspect that $\overline{X}$ might be a, potentially confusing, alternative to $\overline{X}^{\top}$. I've seen $\overline{X}^{\top}$ written as $X^*$ or $X^{\dagger}$ but never just $\overline{X}$.